# NoUIslider - Update range on demand

Tags: javascript, jquery, uislider, nouislider

I have two sliders and I would like to update the range of one slider based on the movement of the other.

For instance; slider_1 and slider_2 both have a range of 1-10.
When I move slider_1 from position 1 to 2, slider_2's range changes from 1-10 to 1-20.
If I move slider_1 from position 2 to 3, slider_3 now has a range from 1-30, and so on.

I initialize the slider like so:

```
  function slider() {
        $(".slider").noUiSlider({
            orientation: "horizontal",
            start: [0],
            range: {
                min: 0,
                max: 10,
            },
            connect: 'lower',
            direction: "ltr",
            step: 1,
        });
    };
```

The best way I can come up with implementing this so far is deconstruct the whole slider, and re-initialize it with the new range each time. 
However I am unsure of how to properly deconstruct the slider.

Any ideas on how this should be done?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

noUiSlider offers an `updateOptions` method, which will keep all settings, save for any new ones you pass it. The [documentation on updating is here](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/more/#section-update).

Starting from noUiSlider 8, you can do:

```
slider.noUiSlider.updateOptions({
    range: {
        'min': 20,
        'max': 30
    }
});
```

*Disclosure: I'm the plugin author.*

Comment: That's it. Thanks for your help! I'm not sure how I missed that in the documentation. Great plugin btw.

Comment: Hi, how can I achieve this in the vue.js version of the plugin, I have been trying to bind the range, but is not affected. @Lg102

Comment: Is there anyway you can just set the min though? If not I have to go recalculate my max.

Comment: @J_sdev You can't update just the `min`, but you can get the current `max` in `slider.noUiSlider.options.range.max`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `destroy()` and then `create()` to dynamically change the range. There is no way to alter the range after the control has been rendered.

```
slider.noUiSlider.destroy()
slider.noUiSlider.create({
    range: {
        'min': 20,
        'max': 30
    }
});
```

Comment: This works for updating the STEPS or START too. For example: if you have a slider with a range in the millions and you want to provide an alt method using inputs to change the sliders. you can destroy and re-create the slider with new START values whenever you like.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ***updateOptions* function** by passing an object as a argument. Yo could build your own "configuration object" programatically like this:

```
config = {
        orientation: "horizontal",
        start: [100,200],
        range: {
            min: 0,
            max: 200,
        },
        connect: 'lower',
        direction: "ltr",
        step: 10,
    };
```

and then UPDATE the slider anywhere in your Javascript:

```
 $(".slider").updateOptions(config);
```

Comment: $(".slider").updateOptions throws  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateOptions' of undefined.. this works 
document.getElementById("price-slider").noUiSlider.updateOptions(config)